# Summarize raw data in new sheet

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

**Note: This question has a [follow up question here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132181/create-summary-of-raw-data-in-new-sheet-2).**

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets: "Raw data" and "Summary". In the raw data sheet there are several blocks with data structured like the image below:

[image]

I want to create a summary of the data below, in the sheet "Summary", looking like this:

[image]

The way I've done this is:

```vb
Sub TransferAndSumElements()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Raw data")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Summary")

    '##############
    ' Copy / Paste first row
    '##############
    ws1.Select
    Rows("1:1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    ws2.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ws2.Paste

    '##############
    ' Set Item names in summary
    '##############

    ws2.Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Knife"
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Fork"
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Spoon"
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Spork"
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Bowl"
    Range("A7").Select

    '##############
    ' Find Elements and Sum
    '##############

    Dim s As Long           ' Sum of elements for each Item
    Dim str As String       ' String in first column in "Summary" (Knife, Fork ...)
    Dim cellstr As String   ' String in first column in "Raw data" (To be searched through)
    Dim DataRange As Range  ' All rows in sheet 1 ("Raw data")

    Dim cellA As Range      ' Used to find cellstr = cellA.Value
    Dim cellB As Range     ' Used to increment s = s + cellB.Value

    ws1.Select              ' Select first worksheet ("This worksheet")
    LastRow = ws1.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Set DataRange = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    For i = 1 To 5          ' Iterate through Knife, Fork .. in "Summary"...

        str = ws2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value     ' Extract names
        s = 0                               ' Initialize sum
        ws1.Activate                        ' Activate Worksheet 1 ("Raw data")

        For r = 1 To LastRow
            Set cellA = Range("A" & r, "A" & r)
            cellstr = cellA.Value
            If InStr(cellstr, str) > 0 Then
                Set cellB = Range("B" & r, "B" & r)
                s = s + cellB.Value
            End If
        Next r

        ws2.Cells(i + 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = s

    Next i

ws2.Activate

End Sub
```

Some stuff that I want to improve, but haven't been able to:

- Automatically fetch the item names from "Raw data". I've tried creating a `Collection`, but I end up with an empty row in between the others (Knife, Fork, Spoon, Spork, Blank, Bowl).

  - I can loop through this list after creating it, and delete the blank row, but I think there should be a way to do this in one go.
- I want to create a list of words ("Knife", "Fork" .. ) and write it to Excel in one command. The way I'm doing it now is to manually write each item name.
- Do the loops make sense, or should I do it in some other way?

And last but not least:

- What about the big picture? Does it make sense to do it like this, or should I do it completely different?

Note: The summary can be sorted alphabetically, by number of elements, or not sorted at all. That doesn't matter.

---

Tab delimited data dump:

```
Item    Number
Knife   2
Fork    2
Spoon   1
Spork   2

Item    Number
Spork   2
Fork    3

Item    Number
Bowl    3
Knife   5
```

Comment: Do you have any power to restructure the raw data? Because that structure desperately needs improving. For more on useful excel data-structures, [Joel Spolsky did an excellent introductory tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nbkaYsR94c)

Comment: I'll check out the link, but first to answer your question: The data above is just a made up format. I chose the format deliberately: Unsorted elements, Variable number of elements in each block, and a header row. I do in fact use a program that outputs data similar to this, only messier. The program is closed, with no API or anything, so I can't alter the formatting of that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should never, ever, be using `Select` or `Active...` in your code.**

Unless you explicitly want your sub to click on a cell, or you explicitly want to work off of a user-selection, this is an incredibly slow, inefficient,  fragile way of doing things.

This:

```
Range("A1").Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "Knife"
```

Or

```
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Knife"
```

Is much better expressed like so:

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Knife"
```

---

Furthermore, `Range("A1")` is *implicitly* calling `[ActiveSheet].Range("A1")`. You should explicitly qualify your references to avoid bugs down the road. Like so:

```
ws2.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Knife"
ws2.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Fork"
ws2.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "Spoon"
```

And then you can use a `With` statement to make it even better:

```
With ws2
    .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Knife"
    .Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "Fork"
    .Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "Spoon"
End With
```